# How to make a live PHP file send data back to the local machine?

Tags: php, html

I am building a phonegap app with integrated contact form (using PHP), I had to add a live .php file to make it work. After `"success"` my online file does not send data back to the local machine, my contact form does not reset and there is no success message. Any suggestion?

```js
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://example.com/contact.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
        success: function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!")
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass("hidden").addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

```html
    <form role="form" id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <!--<label for="name" class="h4">Name</label>-->
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <!--<label for="email" class="h4">Email</label>-->
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <!--<label for="message" class="h4 ">Message</label>-->
            <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right ">Submit</button>
        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </form>
```

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
$errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
$name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
$errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
$email = $_POST["email"];
}

// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
$errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
$message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "example@domain.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
echo "success";
}else{
if($errorMSG == ""){
    echo "Something went wrong :(";
} else {
    echo $errorMSG;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: `<?php if (!$code) {print "Where's your code?";}`

Comment: where's the `<?php` tag? @PedroLobito that'll throw them an error (grin). Edit: ah, there we go ;-)

Comment: I'll add it on v2.0 ;)

Comment: `<?php echo "Is there an *echo* in here?";`

Comment: @PedroLobito I think we got their attention ;-) see the edit.

Comment: :)) there you go guys

Comment: Well far as I can tell, I don't see where you're implementing/calling the `submitForm()` method in any input to call that method. That's all I can tell but I could be wrong. Check the console and use php's error reporting.

Comment: @Fred-ii- A little more help?

Comment: if this is a JS-related issue, I am not the guy for this. I'm a serverside coder mostly.

Comment: I'm getting this on send button `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mywebsite.com/contact.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: https://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `XMLHttpRequest` cannot load `https://mywebsite.com/contact.php`. No
>   '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

You need to enable `CORS` on your server,  please refer to

https://enable-cors.org/

This can be as easy as adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to `https://mywebsite.com/contact.php`, i.e.:

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 # rest of the code...
```